# Compare number with register

Tags: assembly, cmp

I have this code:

```
CMP.B #3,R6L
BLO konec
```

which compare if content of R6L is bigger than 3, but I need opposite of it (find out if R6L is smaller than 3).
I tried change #3 and R6L to CMP.B R6L,#3 but it doesn't work.
I know that it's beginners question, but I really can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare instruction produces enough information to determine all the ordering information—less than, equal to, or greater than. The branch instruction chooses which conditions to branch on. Change `BLO` to `BHI`.

Note: You did not specify the architecture or assembly language, so I am partially guessing about `BHI`. You should check the documentation. Various architectures and assembly languages have variants for slightly different kinds of branches. For example, `BHI` may be for branching if the comparison shows one unsigned value is higher than another unsigned value, while `BGT` may be for branch if the comparison shows one signed value is greater than than another signed value.